# PHP Divide Array By Empty Value

Tags: arrays

This is an array from input field as below

```
Array(
    [0] =>
    [1] => 737
    [2] => 736
    [3] => 735
    [4] => 
    [5] => 748
    [7] => 744
    [8] => 747
    [9] => 746
    [10] => 
    [11] => 748
    [12] => 747
    [13] => 746
    [14] => 745
    [15] => 744
);
```

Is there a way to divide it by empty value and removing the empty value as below:

```
Array(
    [0] => Array(
        [0] => 737
        [1] => 736
        [2] => 735
    )
    [1] => Array(
        [0] => 748
        [1] => 744
        [2] => 747
        [3] => 746
    )
    [2] => Array(
        [0] => 748
        [1] => 747
        [2] => 746
        [3] => 745
        [4] => 744
    )
)
```

Comment: what is "Empty Value" ??

Comment: What do you mean by "Divide without value?"

Comment: Split/divide it into new array foreach spesific value ( in this case if the array key with no value )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to split the array into sub-arrays with the "null" values as delimiters, something like that should do the job:

```
$newArray = array();
$subArray = null;
for ($i = 0; $i < count($array); $i++) {
    if (!$subArray) $subArray = array();

    $v = $array[$i];
    if ($v) {
        array_push($subArray, $v);
    } else {
        if (count($subArray) > 0) array_push($newArray, $subArray);
        $subArray = null;
    }
}

if ($subArray) array_push($newArray, $subArray);
```

Comment: Thanks @Laurent, it works perfectly. I wrote the wrong array index, there is no index 6 in the sample, assume it from 0 to 14.